# Weird letter 'i' in the reference frame title in beamer

Tags: beamer, biblatex, cross-referencing

I am preparing a beamer presentation and when I add a reference and compile it the title of References frame gets and an extra letter 'i'. What is the problem here? see below my code.

Thanks.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{uuc}{rgb}{0.76,0.24,0.13}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibo.bib}

%%%%%%%%%%% Title
\title{Title}
\subtitle{Subtitle}
\author{Author}
\date{}
\institute{Institute}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\useoutertheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
 \setbeamertemplate{frame numbering}[fraction]
\useoutertheme{metropolis}
\useinnertheme{metropolis}
\usefonttheme{metropolis}
\usecolortheme[named=uuc]{structure}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{frame}[t]{Title}
Hello, world!\footcite{ref1}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks, plain,noframenumbering]{References}
\printbibliography[heading = none]  
 \end{frame}

  \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I compile as: PdfLaTeX + Bib(la)tex + PdfLaTeX(x2). And using biber % instead of bibtex %

Comment: If you remove the `allowframebreaks` option, the problem will go away.

Comment: Hi Carlos, thank you very much for your reply. I tried and it did remove the extra 'i'. But if I have to spilt the references into multiple slides then what would be the option?

Comment: It is the roman number 1.  On the next slide it will be `II` for 2 and so on.  To clear this number you can use `\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}{}` before that frame.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It has solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `i` is in fact a roman number `1`; the confusion comes from it being capitalised and in a sans serif font.  On the next continuation slide `i` will be replaced by `ii`, and so on.

You can turn this numbering off with

```
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}{}
```

for example just before the relevant frame(s):

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{lipsum}% for dummy text

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
  \frametitle{Numbered continuation frames}

  \lipsum[1-2]
\end{frame}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}{}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
  \frametitle{Unnumbered continuation frames}

  \lipsum[1-2]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Confusingly the `noframenumbering` option refers to something else, namely frame numbers throughout the document that are often used in footers.